# Why setting variables to itself make things work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two pieces of code, piece #1 didn't work but piece #2 worked.

Piece #1

```
  let g = circle.data(that.nodes, d => d.id);
  g.exit().remove();
  g = g.enter().append("svg:g").call(drag).merge(g)
```

Piece #2

```
  let g = circle.data(that.nodes, d => d.id);
  g.exit().remove();
  g = g.enter().append("svg:g");
  g = g.call(drag).merge(g);
```

However, interestingly, if I log **g** at the end of the not working code, I get:

[image]

But if I log the working code, I actually get:

[image]

Comment: The difference is that `g` has different values when you call `merge()`. In snippet 1, `g` is your update selection; in snippet 2, it’s your enter selection.

Comment: The issue here is quite simple, and Noleli's comment above explained it: you're merging different things. Just stop and check what `g` means at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the issue having already been explained in the comments, a proper answer is necessary.

The main concept here is that some methods, like `enter()`, return a **new** selection. That being said, let's see your working snippet, *Piece #1*:

```
let g = circle.data(that.nodes, d => d.id);
```

This is your update selection, so let's call it `update`.

Then, after that, you have:

```
update = update.enter().append("svg:g").call(drag).merge(update)
```

As previously explained, `enter()` returns a new selection. Let's call it `enter`. So, in fact, you have this:

```
update = enter.merge(update);
```

Which is the correct (idiomatic) way to merge selections.

Now, let's see your second (non working) snippet, *Piece #2*. In the third line you have:

```
update = update.enter().append("svg:g");
```

You just turned `update` into an **enter** selection. So, in the next line, you have this:

```
enter = enter.merge(enter);
```

Which, of course, will not work: you're merging enter selections.